# lodash debounce function does not triggerin in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, lodash, debouncing

I want to use lodash debounce with @input event in my Vue js app. But the defined function is not triggered.

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

const GlobalFunctions = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$debounce = (func, wait, options) => {
      console.log("log1");
      return debounce(func, wait, options);
    };
  }
};

Vue.use(GlobalFunctions);

new Vue({
  el: "#test",
  methods: {
    onInput() {
      this.$debounce(this.callApi, 500, {
        trailing: true
      });
    },
    callApi() {
      console.log("api called!");
    },
  },
});


<
/script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div id="test">
  <input type="text" @input="onInput" />
</div>
```

I created an example for my story. What can be the problem ? I shared link to below

you can see on the console it does not triggered

[Code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-func-does-not-triggered-vyoodd)

Comment: Please, update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's good that there's a demo but the question should contain all necessary information without a need to navigate to external links that may go offline

Comment: Any way, the usual mistake with debounce is that it's called on each call, it physically can't work this way. You can check "related" questions that discuss it. Debounced function should be defined once per component instance, likely in `data`

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the response. As you said, I solved my problem. Actually, I defined debounce as computed.  this is solution link
https://codesandbox.io/s/debounce-func-does-not-triggered-solved-notl88